# get folder address from text file for copy file ( by command )

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, command

I'm tray to save (folder address) to a text file and i want copy file to this address ,
is there any way to use copy command read this text address and copy file to the address

i want make a copy batch program for copy my file to several address in  my pc but get the address from a text file , Addresses are not fixed and often change.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you referencing the folder location from?

Comment: i want make a copy batch program for copy my file to several address in  my pc but get the address from a text file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this ?

```
get-content text_path.txt | foreach { copy file.txt -dest $_ }
```

Comment: tanks for help me, it work

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite clear, what your problem is, but this may help you:

to write something to a file use

```
echo this is my text>file.txt
```

to read it back into a variable use

```
set /p "var="<file.txt
```

Then you can use it:

```
echo I have read: %var%
```

Note: this is the simplest way to do it, but it works only with "one-line-files" - exactly, what you need (according to your description)